# yield* delegate operator in Redux Sagas

Tags: javascript, generator, redux, redux-saga

In the [Redux Sagas Beginner Tutorial](http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html) we are told to write a watcher saga like this:

```
export function* watchIncrementAsync() {
   yield* takeEvery('INCREMENT_ASYNC', incrementAsync)
}
```

Why do we use the `yield*` delegate operator on line 2 instead of just the `yield` operator? Won't they both do the same thing here?

Comment: I guess `takeEvery` returns an iterator and `yield*` delegates to this iterator. A normal `yield` would just return this iterator to the caller.

Comment: What would be the downside of just returning the iterator to the caller? Either way the iterator is run until it is exhausted, which is what I want to happen.

Comment: The caller seems to automatically call the generator. Maybe this is behavior that is particular with Redux Sagas.

Answer (score 0):

As LUH3417 says, takeEver IS a generator, so you yield (delegate to it) in this instance. From the Docs:

```
function* takeEvery(pattern, saga, ...args) {
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(pattern)
    yield fork(saga, ...args.concat(action))
  }
}
```

My guess is it is about control flow. If your iterator does not care to yield anything else but the takeEvery, then I do not see a reason why you need to yield your control flow completely over. If your generator needed to pass control to another generator, then come back, then I see the value of passing control over... but in your example, I don't see a code reason why you'd need to delegate over to takeEvery. If I am incorrect, please let me know.

Comment: This does not appear to answer my question. I'm not required to delegate to the generator for the generator to still be run, so **why not** just use `yield`?

Comment: my guess is it is about control flow. If your iterator does not care to yield anything else but the takeEvery, then I do not see a reason why you need to yield your control flow completely over. If your generator needed to pass control to another generator, then come back, then I see the value of passing control over... but in your example, I don't see a code reason why you'd need to delegate over to takeEvery. If I am incorrect, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

These two links may help explain:
http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/advanced/ComposingSagas.html
http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/advanced/SequencingSagas.html (i this this page was actually added today)

From Composing Sagas:

> `yield*` allows only for sequential composition of tasks, so you can only yield* to one generator at a time

I'm still trying to grok all this myself, but perhaps `yield*` with the `takeEvery` means that with each subsequent `INCREMENT_ASYNC` action, it calls the subtask (`incrementAsync` in your example) but does so sequentially, once the previous subtask has resolved. If you were to use `yield`, then for every `INCREMENT_ASYNC` action it would call the subtask immediately and they would execute and resolve in parallel.

Using `takeLatest` differs from `takeEvery` in that it cancels the previous request to start the new one.

Comment: Links are dead, could You provide alternative please?